# Where can I watch the movie "Reversion"?

Tags: movie

There's a movie I found out a bit about called *[Reversion](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1098369/)*, about people who live in the past, present, and future simultaneously.  It sounded pretty neat, but I don't see it as available (or even existing) on Amazon, and I don't recall seeing it in the theaters.  Is there a way to watch this movie?

Comment: Looks like it was shown in New York City, June 10-16, 2011, and there's no theatre dates after that.  I think you'll have to wait.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shopping recommendation

Comment: @DVK It's not so much a shopping recommendation (which would definitely have nothing to do with the site), but whether the movie is available in any form at all, or has just disappeared from public consumption.  If the question was about Citizen Kane, a movie that is widely and obviously available, it would be silly...but is asking for specific not-readily-available information about the possible availability of the movie itself.

Comment: If anyone is looking for info on the movie, note that it's the [2008 Reversion on imdb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1098369/) ([this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20110831175424/http://www.filmthreat.com/reviews/10982/) says it premiered in 2008 at the Sundance Film Festival), not the [2011 ReVersion on imdb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2465672/), or the [2015 Reversion](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4578084/), or the [2020 Reversion](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3896836/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an independent film, and it appears to have been recently released and is still making the circuit of theaters that will show independent films.  The [film's own website](https://web.archive.org/web/20111225140639/http://www.reversionthemovie.com/) has information on it and you can even subscribe to news on the movie.

You can also subscribe to their Twitter feeds, "Like" them on Facebook and get news from them in several other ways.  While they do not have a forum or a place to ask questions, at least you can get their news.

They also have a [press kit](http://reversionthemovie.com/files/REVERSIONPressKit5.11.docx) you can download, but it does not give planned showing or DVD release dates (as of now).

Comment: The website links are dead

Comment: @Valorum I updated the film website link with a version from archive.org, but they didn't have the press kit (linked from the [press page](https://web.archive.org/web/20110829203843/http://reversionthemovie.com/press.html)) archived unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [film's website](http://reversionthemovie.com/) it was released in movie theaters in New York back in June.  Unfortunately their website doesn't list any home media release information.  The [writer and director's website](http://trachinger.com/) makes no mention of a home media release.  Neither does the [film studio's website](http://lanestreetpictures.com/).  The [film's Facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Reversion/7222181913) is similarly devoid of information on future releases.

At present, it appears there's no way to see the film.  It's not in theaters, and there are no indicators it will be released on home media.